# Download a flash video (not from a popular video community)

Tags: video, flash, downloads

There are a lot of tools to download videos from Youtube, Dailymotion, Vimeo, etc. but I'd be interested in a more generic way to download flash videos, for example the ones here: http://www.canalplus.fr/index.php?pid=3351

Answer (score 6):

Using Firefox with the [FlashGot!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/220/) [[image] **Firefox add-on**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/220/) has worked well for me. Wikipedia's [[image] FlashGot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FlashGot) article also lists some alternatives.

Comment: What is the formatting code for that Firefox add-on link?

Comment: @lovinglinux -- View the page source, and you'll see it.  I'd post it, but I think it's too much format foo for a comment.  It's Ctrl-U in firefox to display the page source.

Comment: it would not work on the canalplus video posted

Answer (score 5):

[Video Download Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3006/) is the best extension for downloading videos from streaming sites. However some sites have protection and won't allow you to download.

For generic method, grab the videos from the /tmp folder or the browser cache folder. The location depends on the video player being used by the web site.

Comment: again, it would not work on the canalplus video posted

Answer (score 3):

On Linux you have two additional possibilities. For Flash files transmitted using http - that includes the likes of youtube, dailymotion - the downloaded videos are stored as `/tmp/Flash*` while they're being played back. If the files are transferred using rtmp, a proprietary protocol, you can try to find the relevant URLs and download using `rtmpdump`. This can sometimes be as simple as looking at the .html file, but it can also involve packet capturing to find the relevant parameters to supply to `rtmpdump`.

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of flash, the video is saved in your browswer cache. The easiest way to ignore that fact and download the video, is to use [flashgot](http://flashgot.net/). You can download videos from almost any site with it. It uses a detection method that can capture most videos on almost any site.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome :

1. Open up developer tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>).
2. Load the page which contains video.
3. Click on *Network* Tab (in developer tools) and click on *Type* Column and locate the flash or video type ..
4. Next after locating the type click on corresponding row and locate the file. It's something like videoplayback.
5. Right click and copy the link address and choose *open in new tab*

Video starts downloading ...

You can do this to download youtube/facebook or any other community video.